# MKMapView not displaying map

Tags: iphone, dictionary, mkmapview

*Note this works perfectly in xcode and is only a problem on a iPhone running IOS 4.2.1

When I set the map to fit a region it does not refresh the map until I touch the screen. The bit of code I use is:

```
MKCoordinateRegion scaledRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
[mapView setRegion:scaledRegion animated:YES];
```

This does move the map to the correct region which I can see when I touch the screen but until I touch the screen I get a grey screen with lots of grid lines across it.

It almost seems like the map is waiting for some sort of refresh event. I have also tried the following code with no success.

```
MKCoordinateRegion scaledRegion = [mapView regionThatFits:region];
[mapView setRegion:scaledRegion animated:YES];
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:mapView.region.center animated:NO];
```

It is also worth noting this is running in a thread.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: I have taken out the multi threading code and it is still a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very weird I have turned off the animation with the following code

```
[mapView setRegion:scaledRegion animated:YES];
```

to

```
[mapView setRegion:scaledRegion animated:NO];
```

And it has started working? I do not understand why?